# Objective c wrapper for a c file

Tags: objective-c, c, ios6, wrapper

I went through quite a number of websites, but everywhere they have given how to write a wrapper for a c++ library.

Now, I have a .c file which i want to integrate to my application. Since Objective c is an objected oriented extension of c, will i actually have to write wrapper for it? if yes, how to do it? if i dont have to, then how to use the c code in my project?

**EDIT :** ok.. what i have to do is add the file into my project and use the functions? how exactly to do it?? just like normal c call? what if i have to pass parameters?

Let say i have a function which returns a string, first of all how do i call that function? and if it returns a string, can i store that value in a normal NSString?? or should i declare a c string for it??

Thanks in advance

Comment: You can use your C code in your objective-c. You don't have to write a wrapper for it, unless you want to do it because the complexity of C code

Comment: yes, code is quite complex.. it implements zrtp protocol.. please see the edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use your C code as usual:

```
-(void)writeString:(NSString*)data toFile:(NSString*)filename {
    FILE* output = fopen([filename UTF8String], "w");
    fprintf(output, "%s", [data UTF8String]);
    fclose(output);
}
```

For other .c files, simply #include the corresponding header. Then, you can just call its functions.

For example, if this was foo.h:

```
int add(int a, int b);
```

And foo.c:

```
#include "foo.h"

int add(int a, int b) {
    return a + b;
}
```

Then in your Objective-C code (Bar.m):

```
-(int)addA:(int)a andB:(int)b {
    return add(a, b);
}
```

That is basically a wrapper right there. However, wrappers are not needed for C code in Objective-C. Even C++ functions do not need wrappers, as there are .mm files which are Objective-C++ sources.

Edit:

To call C functions with parameters, just call them with parameters. Literally ANY valid C program is also a valid Objective-C program. If it can compile as a .c file, it'll compile as a .m file.

To convert a C string (`char*`) to an NSString:

```
const char* myString = "Hello!";
NSString* myNSString = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:myString];
```

Comment: Thanks for this clarification.. how do i just call the function? functionName(); like that?? like how we call in c? please see the edit..

Comment: C can be mixed freely with Objective-C. You would call it exactly the same as you would in a pure C program.

Comment: thats great :) thanks a lot.. i'll just try what you have told :)